# How to stop this constant stream of logs in webview screen?

Tags: android, flutter

```
D/BufferQueueProducer(30418): [SurfaceTexture-0-30418-0](this:0x94f72000,id:0,api:1,p:392,c:30418) cancelBuffer: slot 2
```

D/BufferQueueProducer(30418): SurfaceTexture-0-30418-0 cancelBuffer: slot 0
D/BufferQueueProducer(30418): SurfaceTexture-0-30418-0 cancelBuffer: slot 2
D/BufferQueueProducer(30418): SurfaceTexture-0-30418-0 cancelBuffer: slot 0
D/BufferQueueProducer(30418): SurfaceTexture-0-30418-0 cancelBuffer: slot 2
D/BufferQueueProducer(30418): SurfaceTexture-0-30418-0 cancelBuffer: slot 0
D/BufferQueueProducer(30418): SurfaceTexture-0-30418-0 cancelBuffer: slot 2
D/BufferQueueProducer(30418): SurfaceTexture-0-30418-0 cancelBuffer: slot 0
D/BufferQueueProducer(30418): SurfaceTexture-0-30418-0 cancelBuffer: slot 2
D/BufferQueueProducer(30418): SurfaceTexture-0-30418-0 cancelBuffer: slot 0
D/BufferQueueProducer(30418): SurfaceTexture-0-30418-0 cancelBuffer: slot 2
D/BufferQueueProducer(30418): SurfaceTexture-0-30418-0 cancelBuffer: slot 0
D/BufferQueueProducer(30418): SurfaceTexture-0-30418-0 cancelBuffer: slot 2

I'm getting the constant stream of the above-mentioned log as soon as webview activity is loaded. This stream is annoying and I'm unable to see my own logs. How to stop them or at least filter them? I'm using visual studio code.

Comment: try this https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=nertilpoci.FilterDebugWindow

Comment: have you found any solution?

Comment: Have you fount any sol?

Comment: the above issue is still happening especially when using Google maps on flutter. any one with a solution?

Comment: This keeps happening to me while using Camera in flutter please provide any solution if u get any

Comment: Any solution found? 
Guys this is not about filtering the logs, but prevent it to be logged

Answer (score 3):

if you are using android studio or other jet brains products there is an option to use right click on a log line and choose "**Fold Lines Like This**", then press "**Ok**".

Then the similar logs will be hidden by green area. To show again click on a green area.

Answer (score 2):

Quick hack is to type `!BufferQueueProducer` in the search field of the debug console, this way any log message contains the word *BufferQueueProducer** will be exclude.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I run an ads on my app and it seems like I can not turn off the ads log. I think it's because the way the ads work by refreshing it's content, therefore I comment my code that run the ads and the constant stream disappeared. Maybe it can works on your case as well